# settings for clickable image in photo grid

Tags: jquery, html, css

The problem is that I have created two 50/50 grid as follows

```
Block A | Block B
Block A | Block B
```

what I'm trying to do is inserting clickable image which is easy task to do. However, my problem is with the dimensions of the images. My problem arises whenever I test the app in the emulator the images either stretch all over the block which is good but unfortunately the image got blurry and not very clear. Another approach, I resized an image and inserted it in each block, and when i tested it the blurry affect disappear but the image is too small. I used (64*64). now before u tell me to resized the image to other dimensions i could do that but would it be a good solution?? i mean the app is hybrid which means it can be deployed on different platforms.

for stretching the image i used the following css

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

- what is the most practical solution to solve this issue? resized for
  each targeted device or use css to stretch images for all devices?
- do extensions of the image make any difference?
- is there a standard dimensions to use for such case regardless the targeted platform or
  the targeted devices?

Comment: Can you explain what app and emulator you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approaches**

There a lot of options available to you and here are a few:

**1)** You can serve up images at the maximum size that they'll be used at and use CSS that will allow them to scale down smoothly.

***Pros:*** Simple implementation and easy to manage.
***Cons:*** Depending on device/platform you may be delivering resources that are too large and may affect performance.

**2)** Use a polyfill for images like [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) which let you use the `<picture>` element along with using the new `<img>` attributes of `sizes` and `srcset`. Doesn't have to be *Picturefill* specifically but an client side tool that helps you determine what size of images to serve to the user.

***Pros:*** Supply a list of images to used based on varying criteria. When you need [art direction](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/#cad-middle) for your images. Let's the browser and other factors decide which image should be served.
***Cons:*** Takes more time to configure and fine tune. Some legacy support issues for

**3)** You could attempt to do feature detection from from the server side an then serve up the appropriate image sizes.

***Pros:*** Can fine tune per device/platform. ***Cons:*** Not as flexible due to fine tuned per device/platform. Feature detection from the server side is not very reliable. More resources, templates to manage etc.

**4)** A mix of both client side and server side solutions, see [RESS](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1392).

Plus others, many of which fall somewhere between what is mentioned above.

**Image Filetype**

**JPG** photo realistic images like a portrait of a person due to the high variation of colors and color gradients. Does not have transparency.

**PNG** photo realistic images like a portrait of a person but will likely have a larger filesize than the *JPG* equivalent. Has transparency.

**GIF** small set of colors available. Good for a small set of colors and a simple logo or set of shapes. Has transparency.

Here's some image type [examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/gif-png-jpg-which-one-to-use/).

> Any additions or corrections to this list are welcome.